# MongoDB import CSV ignoring errors

Tags: mongodb, csv, import

Is it possible to import data from CSV into mongoDB using *mongoimport*, but ignoring any errors during parsing csv row?
I have a csv file with about 200 millions of rows, and some of them are incorrectly formatted, and each iteration of fix/try takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [--parseGrace skipRow](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-parsegrace) option.

```
mongoimport --type csv --parseGrace skipRow --file millionrecords.csv --headerline
```

> --parseGrace *grace*
>
> Default: stop
>
> New in version 3.4.
>
> Specifies how mongoimport handles type coercion failures when
>   importing CSV or TSV files with *--columnsHaveTypes*.
>
> --parseGrace has no effect when importing JSON documents.
>
> - **autoCast**   : Assigns a type based on the value of the field. For example, if a field is defined as a double and the value for that
>     field was "foo", mongoimport would make that field value a string
>     type.
> - **skipField**  :   For the row being imported, mongoimport does not include the field whose type does not match the expected type.
> - **skipRow**    :   mongoimport does not import rows containing a value whose type does not match the expected type.
> - **stop**       : mongoimport returns an error that ends the import.